# Popoverviewcontroller for iphone

Tags: ios4, uipopovercontroller

I need to use a UIPopOverController that containing a tableview in it for my iPhone app with out using any additional framework, can any one help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIPopOverController is exclusive to iPad, cannot use on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourTableViewController *controller = [[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 10, 10) inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

OR

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: I implented the same in my iphone app,the app is crashing with  an excepton ,"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
"